# If $A\cap \{\tau\leq t\}\in \mathcal F_t$, will we have that $A\cap \{\tau>t\}\in \mathcal F_t$?

Tags: probability

Let $\{F_t\}$ a filtration and $\tau$ a stopping time. Let $A\in \sigma (\bigcup_{t}\mathcal F_t)$. Let $A\in \mathcal F_\tau$. In particular, we have that $$A\cap \{\tau\leq t\}\in \mathcal F_t,$$
but will we have that $$A\cap \{\tau>t\}\in \mathcal F_t \ \ ?$$

The best I can do is $$A\cap\{\tau\leq t\}=(A^c\cup \{\tau\leq t\})^c,$$
and there is a priori no reason that belong in $\mathcal F_t$, does it ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot say that $A \cap \{\tau >t\} \in \mathcal F_t$ for every $t$. If this is true then $A =(A \cap \{\tau \leq t\})\cup (A \cap \{\tau >t\})$ would be in $\mathcal F_t$ but this need be true for every $t$.